# JIRA Rest Client SSL Certification

Tags: ssl, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I want to communicate with my JIRA server.

I would like to use the JIRA Client Framework and [JIRA Rest Client](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Home).

```
final JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("https://issues.teamspace.local/jira");
final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "username", "password");
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to perform this and I'm not finding anything useful in the web.

Comment: check this if you have questions ask me
 https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/263719/using-oauth-and-the-jira-java-rest-client

Answer (score 0):

check it over here

https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Tutorial

```
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        final JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
        final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("http://localhost:8090/jira");
        final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "yourusername", "yourpassword");
        final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
        final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("TST-1", pm);

        System.out.println(issue);

        // now let's vote for it
        restClient.getIssueClient().vote(issue.getVotesUri(), pm);

        // now let's watch it
        restClient.getIssueClient().watch(issue.getWatchers().getSelf(), pm);

        // now let's start progress on this issue
        final Iterable<Transition> transitions = restClient.getIssueClient().getTransitions(issue.getTransitionsUri(), pm);
        final Transition startProgressTransition = getTransitionByName(transitions, "Start Progress");
        restClient.getIssueClient().transition(issue.getTransitionsUri(), new TransitionInput(startProgressTransition.getId()), pm);

        // and now let's resolve it as Incomplete
        final Transition resolveIssueTransition = getTransitionByName(transitions, "Resolve Issue");
        Collection<FieldInput> fieldInputs = Arrays.asList(new FieldInput("resolution", "Incomplete"));
        final TransitionInput transitionInput = new TransitionInput(resolveIssueTransition.getId(), fieldInputs, Comment.valueOf("My comment"));
        restClient.getIssueClient().transition(issue.getTransitionsUri(), transitionInput, pm);

    }

    private static Transition getTransitionByName(Iterable<Transition> transitions, String transitionName) {
        for (Transition transition : transitions) {
            if (transition.getName().equals(transitionName)) {
                return transition;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the dependency set up [here](https://scottizu.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/using-the-atlassian-jira-rest-client/)

This is how you create the client.

```
URI serverURI = new URL("url").toURI();
JiraRestClientFactory jiraFactory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
JiraRestClient client = jiraFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(serverURI,"username","password");
```

[Here's the documentation for the API.](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client-api/2.0.0-m25/jira-rest-java-client-api/apidocs/)